# Reduce the minimum iPhone volume (bluetooth speakers)

Tags: iphone, sound-volume

When connecting my iPhone (4S or 6) to a JBL Flip 2 bluetooth speakers, the minimum volume is too loud. Under that, it mutes. It is not a problem of the speakers, as the volume using another, non-Apple, phone, can be reduced much more.

Is there a way to get finer decrements of the volume than those of the side buttons? Moving the slider suggests so, but it is difficult to control in such small space.

I tried using a volume cap as suggested elsewehere, but there seems to have no effect on the volume precision.

Any ideas?

Comment: AFIK there is no way using iPhone controls to make them more fine resolution. Using the buid in Volume on the speaker is the only option to control the low and high range. If it is to loud at minimum input then reduce the volume on the speakers.

Comment: @Buscar웃 the volume control in the speaker just modify the iphone own settings, with the same precision.

Comment: I am having the same problem and am considering returning the speaker as this does not happen with my Bose Bluetooth speaker.

Answer (score 1):

I was just here searching for a way to do exactly this (reduce the "Step" for volume adjustments).  I gave up and went to solve a couple more music/iPhone related problems.

Anyway, turns out that if you have the Apple Watch and use it's built-in volume control, there are no stops--even when playing through bluetooth it let me adjust all the way from really loud down to whisper.

Another thing to notice--after I adjust my phone volume with the watch I think it somehow affects the built-in controls and I'm able to get a different range but I can't put my finger on exactly what's going on--and after I leave it sit for a while it goes back to it's old behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Slide up the Control Center. There you'll have a slider to control volume which allows stepless adjusting.